# Loading resources in index.html, from dist fails, contrary to working npm run dev cmd

Tags: javascript, web, npm, webpack

In my project, I am using Webpack 4 to convert my `.scss` files to a `main.bundle.css` file and my `.vue` and `.js` files to a single `main.bundle.js`. So far it works successfully and I can see my website properly when I run `npm run dev`, and see my assets generate in ./dist when I run `npm run prod`.

However, when I click on the HTML file in Explorer (subsequently visiting `file:///C:/path/to/project/index.html` in an internet browser), I see a blank white screen, nothing compared to when I run `npm run dev`.

I'm puzzled, because in my HTML file, I add link and script tags for the `main.bundle.css` and `main.bundle.js`, but they do not load in the browser.

In Mozilla Firefox, I receive the following 'warning': `Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///dist/main.js”` (the `main.bundle.css` file also fails to load also, but there is no mention of it in the console). In Google Chrome, I receive the following error (for both files): `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Edit: I should note that my directory structure is the following (some files excluded for convenience): 
- Project
- - dist
- - - assets 
- - - main.bundle.css
- - - main.bundle.js
- - src
- - - assets
- - - components (containing various VueJS components) 
- - - css
- - - js
- - - index.js 
- - index.html
- - webpack.config.js

I'm not sure how to approach this issue. I assume it is either a VueJS or Webpack issue. Any help would be appreciated; the code is below.

My `webpack.config.js` is shown below. To my knowledge, I am setting up Webpack fine (there are no errors when running `npm run dev` or `npm run prod`).

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist'
  },
   module: {
      rules: [
        // Change preset to 'env', but save that for later
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
          }
        },
        {
         test: /\.vue$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'vue-loader',
       },
       {
         test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: [
           MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           'css-loader',
           'sass-loader' // Loads a sass/scss file and compiles it t CSS
         ]
       },
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
           MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           'css-loader'
         ]
       },
       // This gets all of the files and puts them in a fonts folder into the dist
       // (fine tune this later)
       {
         test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'file-loader',
         options: {
           name: '[name].[ext]',
           outputPath: 'assets'
         }
       }
      ]
   },
   resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
      },
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: '[name].bundle.css',
        chunckFilename: '[id].css'
      })
    ]
}
```

My `index.html` file is shown below.

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/main.bundle.css">
  <title>Periodic Table of the Elements</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- NAVIGATION <-->
  <div id="navigation-el"> </div>

  <!-- OPTIONS -->
  <div id="options-el"></div>

  <!-- GRID CONTAINER -->
  <div id="grid-el"></div>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <div id="footer-el"> </div>

  <!-- Development mode -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If it matters, the following is my index.js

```
// index.js
import './css/main.scss';

import Vue from 'vue';
// Assign Vue to window object in index.js; Vue() is now a global property of the window object
window.Vue = Vue;

import Navigation from './components/Navigation.vue';
import Options from './components/Options.vue';
import PeriodicTable from './components/PeriodicTable.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';

// This may be formated incorrectly
new Vue({
  render: k => k(Navigation)
}).$mount('#navigation-el')

new Vue({
  render: j => j(Options)
}).$mount('#options-el')

new Vue({
  // Render is method of vue instance, means replace part you are slecting the dom with, with some other code
   render: h => h(PeriodicTable)
 }).$mount('#grid-el')

new Vue({
  render: m => m(Footer)
}).$mount('#footer-el')
```

If you need to know what versions of particular plugins etc. I am using, the following are my development dependencies; I understand that there are some packages I have installed that are not used - they will be removed.

```
 // package.json
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
  ...
```

Again, any and all help is appreciated. I'm not sure how to approach this problem and any pointers to the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: file explore use file protocol, not HTTP protocol, that is the reason it is blank, use any kind of web server ( local ) browse using HTTP

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake
Oh ok, that makes a bit more sense, but when I git push this to a Github pages page, it is still white. Shouldn't it work because Github pages uses HTTPS, or does it still not work because Github pages is a static service?

Comment: git hub pages should work because it is http,

Comment: better to run it in local server by copying file, and add those to git hub pull request. also check the dist folder has specific files, also you need to push dist files to github not src